# Grade Calculator

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to do this exercise:

Create a function workOutGradeAv - this method will read in some grades, then work out and display the average grade.

Display a meaningful introductory message.
1.1 Declare any variables you need later in the code.

1.2 Display a message asking for 5 grades in 5 separate input boxes on a HTML form. You should also explain that they should input one grade per line 
1.3 It should not be possible to submit the form unless all 5 fields are entered correctly and in values that are within the grade boundary

1.4 Use a do loop(to control program flow) that:

1.4.1   reads the grade from the input form into a variable. 
1.4.2   (Using a logical operator) a conditional statement (If) to check if the grade is outside the range 0 to 101 (use Boolean OR) and print error message if that is true. 
1.4.3   else if the grade is not 101, then add the grade to your

total.
end the do loop and check the grade is not 101

1.5 Calculate the average grade and display the result with a suitable message.

My code is this:
Assess1Grades.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Grade Assessor</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Grade Assessor<h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <form action="grades.php" method="post">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Enter 5 grades. One per each line:
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Grade 1: <input type="number" name="grade1" required>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Grade 2: <input type="number" name="grade2" required>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Grade 3: <input type="number" name="grade3" required>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Grade 4: <input type="number" name="grade4" required>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Grade 5: <input type="number" name="grade5" required>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <input type="submit">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </form>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

grades.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Grade Assessor</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Grade Assessor<h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                The Average grade is:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                function workOutGradeAv() {
                                    $averagegrade=$grades/5;
                                    echo "$averagegrade";
                                }
                                $grades=0;
                                do {
                                    if ($_Post["grade1"] < 0 or $_Post["grade1"] > 101) {
                                        echo "Error! Check Input.";
                                    } elseif ($_Post["grade2"] < 0 or $_Post["grade2"] > 101) {
                                        echo "Error! Check Input.";
                                    } elseif ($_Post["grade3"] < 0 or $_Post["grade3"] >101)  {
                                        echo "Error! Check Input.";
                                    } elseif ($_Post["grade4"] < 0 or $_Post["grade4"] >101)  {
                                        echo "Error! Check Input.";
                                    } elseif ($_Post["grade5"] < 0 or  $_Post["grade5"]>101 ) {
                                        echo "Error! Check Input.";
                                    } else {
                                        $grades = $grades + $_Post["grade1"] + $_Post["grade2"] + $_Post["grade3"] + $_Post["grade4"] + $_Post["grade5"];
                                    }
                                }
                                while ($_Post["grade1"]!= 101);
                                workOutGradeAv();
                                ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I submit the form the output is just "The Average Grade is" and there is no result. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Pedro, what is $_Post? $_Post is undefined... you should be using $_POST (all caps). I assume you don't have error reporting turned on, please turn error reporting on.

Comment: First of all, you are using $_Post ... it should be: $_POST. PHP is case sensitive. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Thanks for crashing my browser...What is the do while loop doing?

Comment: Hey. Sorry. This is my third exercise. My teacher told me to use it. I've put the exercise that he gave me.

Comment: no worries, all the best with your course!

Comment: Thanks. But how could I use the `do loop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors in `grades.php`

1)Remove unnecessary `do while` loop

2)replace `$_Post` to `$_POST`.`PHP` is case sensitive language.

3)to display grade in function you have to declare `grades` as global. Or pass it as parameter.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Grade Assessor</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Grade Assessor<h2>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
The Average grade is:
</td>
<td>
<?php

function workOutGradeAv($grades) {

$averagegrade=$grades/5;
echo "$averagegrade";
}
$grades=0;

if ($_POST["grade1"] < 0 || $_POST["grade1"] > 101)   {
echo "Error! Check Input.";
} elseif ($_POST["grade2"] < 0 or $_POST["grade2"] > 101) {
echo "Error! Check Input.";
} elseif ($_POST["grade3"] < 0 or $_POST["grade3"] >101)  {
echo "Error! Check Input.";
} elseif ($_POST["grade4"] < 0 or $_POST["grade4"] >101)  {
echo "Error! Check Input.";
} elseif ($_POST["grade5"] < 0 or  $_POST["grade5"]>101 ) {
echo "Error! Check Input.";
} else {
$grades = $grades + $_POST["grade1"] + $_POST["grade2"] + $_POST["grade3"] + $_POST["grade4"] + $_POST["grade5"];
} 

workOutGradeAv($grades);
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But one of the criteria is to se the `do loop`.                            1.4 Use a do loop(to control program flow) that: 

1.4.1 reads the grade from the input form into a variable. 
1.4.2 (Using a logical operator) a conditional statement (If) to check if the grade is outside the range 0 to 101 (use Boolean OR) and print error message if that is true. 
1.4.3 else if the grade is not 101, then add the grade to your 

total.